# Class is missing in the NuGet package but exists with a project reference

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm currently having a little problem in one of my Android Binding projects.
The project has the target frameworks MonoAndroid and net6.0-android.
The project SDK is set to MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/3.0.44.

Now to the problem at hand:

If I directly use the Binding project in another project by adding it to the same solution and then referencing it, everything works fine. This has been useful so far to test and improve the binding. If I now generate a NuGet package from the Binding and use it in my test project, I get errors like this: *"The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*. So I disassembled the NuGet package a bit and looked at the contained DLLs with dotPeek. Both for MonoAndroid and net6.0-android. The "missing" classes are included in both. The only hint I have right now are some warnings I get in the Android Binding project. Anyone who has ever done a binding project knows these. Typical warnings like: *"For type 'Foo', base interface 'Foo' is invalid"*. These errors sometimes also refer to the classes that are then displayed as "Missing".

What makes me suspicious that the error lies here, however, is that as a direct reference these classes and thus also the Binding project itself work.

Has anyone perhaps had a similar error before or has an idea what it could be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a similar problem, one binding project works when referenced but when its .dll is referenced it causes the problems (at first it was only in release mode but later even in debug as far as I remember). Anyway I've never resolved it as referencing the project was acceptable to me.

Comment: Super weird... continuing to reference the project is unfortunately not an option for me. If I get the problem solved I'll let you know!

Comment: As a test, if you target only ONE framework when you build Nuget, does it then work for that framework? And to not overlook the obvious: You do have appropriate `using Foo;` at top of source file that tries to reference? Are you sure you haven't defined Nuget such that you now need something like `using MyNuget.Foo;`?

Comment: The error persists even if I use only one framework. Project as reference works, but not as NuGet. I could have perhaps expressed this differently: From let's say 25 classes exactly 2 are missing, since all are in the same namespace I can exclude usings as error.

Comment: Hey, I was able to solve the problem. But for me it was due to an explicit error in how .aar files in AndroidLibraries are packaged in NuGets. After a lot of analysis of the NuGet file with dotPeek I found out that the .aar file was missing and opened an issue in Xamarin-Android. The error was then confirmed and a temporary workaround was given. So if someone runs into a similar problem: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7040